# Looking for good example of using get() with an AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm curious about the `get(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)` function in AsyncTask, but I'm having a hard time locating an example of it's usage.

[get(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Can anyone provide an example of it's use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears as though [`AsyncTask.get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) blocks the caller thread, where [`AsyncTask.execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) does not.

You might want to use `AsyncTask.get()` for test cases where you want to test a particular Web Service call, but you do not need it to be asynchronous and you would like to control how long it takes to complete. Or any time you would like to test against your web service in a test suite.

Syntax is the same as execute:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}

new DownloadFilesTask().get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: great answer, thanks! I guess the odd thing is that you need to catch the TimeoutException of get(). I think my confusion here was that you cannot call this from the main thread if you have any networking in it.

Comment: If it blocks the caller thread.. How does this differs from a method call that run on same thread sequentially?

Comment: @citizenconn hey..maybe this is a question for you :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351918/how-to-force-the-asynctask-to-wait

Answer (score 4):

Another use of AsyncTask is to know when several AsyncTasks have processed:

```
AsyncTask1 a1 = new AsyncTask();
AsyncTask1 a2 = new AsyncTask();

a1.execute();
a2.execute();

a1.get();
a2.get();

Log.d("Example", "a1 and a2 have both finished, you can now proceed");
```

Comment: good point, it's worth noting that this will block the UI thread though