# AsyncTask get() sometimes freezes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a simple class to handle http requests. Because this task needs to be performed in a different thread since Android 3.1 I have created the followin thread blocking class witch uses get to wait to the request to complete.

First time it works but after that I always get the time out or just freezes the application. Here is my code:

```
class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        DefaultHttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            String url = params[0].replace(" ", "%20");
            HttpResponse resp = cli.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            String tmp = "",rezultat = "";
            setResult("");

            while ((tmp = read.readLine()) != null)
            {
                rezultat = rezultat + tmp;
            }
            setResult(rezultat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            setResult("");
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }



}

static public String req(Context ctx,String url,boolean want_resp)
{

    if (isOnline(ctx))
    {
        HttpRequester cc = new HttpRequester();
        MakeRequest test = cc.new MakeRequest();
        test.execute(url);
        if (want_resp)
        {
            try {
                test.get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "FAIL";
            }
            return result;
        }
        else return "OK";
    }
    else 
        {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Internet connection required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setResult("");
        return "";
        }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070082/looking-for-good-example-of-using-get-with-an-asynctask-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AsyncTask.get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.**So it blocks the UI**.

```
test.get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

**This will make your main thread wait for the result of the AsyncTask at most 30000 milliseconds.**

Comment: the problem is that i just make a get request

Answer (score 2):

Docs itself mentions that,

> [public final Result get ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)
>
> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
> its result.

So, this method will block the UI until your AsyncTask is running. You can simply Update your UI on `onPostExecute()` that executes on the UI thread.

If you are interested that to return some value from AsyncTask you can use your own listener which may be BroadCastReceiver or Interface. [Here is an example from my github](https://github.com/lalit3686/AsyncTaskReturnValue)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a more common [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) approach ?

I mean as Lalit point out, get the result on the appropriate function :

Return the result on your doInBackground

```
return rezultat;
```

And handle it on the onPostExecute of your MakeRequest

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 }
```

Don't forget to change your AsyncTask signature

```
class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
```