# how to force the AsyncTask to wait

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

i want the AsyncTask to wait till it finishes. so i wrote the below code and i used .get() method as follows and as shown below in the code

```
    mATDisableBT = new ATDisableBT();
```

but at run time the .get() doesnt force ATDisableBT to wait, becuase in the logcat i receive mixed order of messages issued from ATDisableBT and ATEnableBT
which means .get() on ATDisableBT did not force it to wait

how to force the AsyncTask to wait

**code**:

```
//preparatory step 1
    if (this.mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mATDisableBT = new ATDisableBT();
        try {
            mATDisableBT.execute().get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //enable BT.
    this.mATEnableBT = new ATEnableBT();
    this.mATEnableBT.execute();
```

Comment: Why are you using an AsyncTask if you want it to block?

Comment: @Fildor please tell me what do u recommend it such situation

Comment: It's hard to recommend something. The snippet is a little bit out of context. Enable/Disable BT sounds like "Bluetooth" ... So this looks like you are trying to disable and enable Bluetooth for whatever reason. Is that correct?

Comment: @Fildor yes..correct

Comment: Correct me if i am rite or not. You want to execute `mATDisableBT` first and then finish of `mATDisableBT` you want to execute `mATEnableBT `?? If thats the situation then its very easy

Answer (score 1):

You should execute AsyncTask on UI thread, so using get() - which will block it makes no sense - it might get you ANR error.

If you are on HONEYCOMB and up, then AsyncTasks are executed on single executor thread, serially - so your mATEnableBT should get executed after mATDisableBT. For more see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)

You might also switch from AsyncTask to Executors. AsyncTask is implemented using executors. By creating single threaded executor you make sure tasks will get executed serially:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
//...

  executor.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // your mATDisableBT code
    }
  });
  executor.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // your mATEnableBT code
    }
  });
```

Comment: He could as well put both blocking operations into doInBackground and notify UI when done, no? We'd have one single ATRestartBT or something alike ... that would be my (naïve) approach.

Comment: You mean with third AsyncTask? I suppose it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

**doInBackground** of AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
   Log.i("doInBackground", "1");

    synchronized (this) {
    try {
          mAsyncTask.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   Log.i("doInBackground", "2");

 return null;
}
```

**Outside** this **function** from where you have to n**strong text**otify **AsyncTask to release** from **wait state**:

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 2000) {
 @Override
 public void onTick(long l) {

   }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
      synchronized (mAsyncTask) {
       mAsyncTask.notify();
     }
   }
}.start();
```

Here I have **notified** AsyncTask by CountDownTimer **after** **2 seconds**.

Hope this will help you.